# ¿Cómo ejecutar 2 funciones al mismo tiempo?

Tags: c, asincronismo

Tengo una funcion:

```
void Musica(void);
```

La misma emite ondas de sonido a través de una señal PWM. Ondas intermitentes, controladas por frecuencia. Y:

```
void Juego(void);
```

Que contiene la lógica del juego Space invaders.

¿Cómo se pueden ejecutar ambas funciones al mismo tiempo de manera que se pueda emitir sonido y ejecutar la lógica de juego?
El usuario debería poder escuchar la música de fondo mientras juega.

Estoy utilizando Code Composser Studio

Comment: O sea que la funcion `void Musica(void)` está diseñada para no terminar nunca?

Comment: No.
La funcion dura aproximadamente 7 segundos, temporizado con un Timer.
Pero la idea, es ejecutar los sonidos emitidos a medida que se va ejecutando el juego.

Comment: Tienes varias opciones: puedes usar hilos (_threads_), o que todo el código se centre en `Musica( )` y, en lo *huecos* de ejecución de la misma, se ejecute la lógica del juego. En ambos casos, la respuesta es demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio.

Answer (score 2):

Deberías usar threads:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

pthread_t tid[2];

void *doSomeThing(void *arg)
{
   unsigned long i = 0;
   pthread_t id = pthread_self();

   if(pthread_equal(id,tid[0]))
   {
      prosamientoMusica();
   }
   else
   {
      procesamientoJuego();
   }

   return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
   int i = 0;
   int err;

   while(i < 2)
   {
      err = pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
      if (err != 0)
         printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
      else
         printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");
      i++;
   }

   sleep(5);
   return 0;
}
```